# How does this servlet code compiles

Tags: java, servlets

I have a following legacy code:

```
Map<String, String> vars = request.getParameterMap(); // (point 1) request is HttpServletRequest
    try{
        for (Entry paramEntry : vars.entrySet()) {
            String paramKey = (String)paramEntry.getKey();
            String[] paramValues = (String[])paramEntry.getValue();// (point 2)
        }
```

According to [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) `getParameterMap()` should return `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]>`. But in my eclipse this code compiles absolutely fine and this code is running since ages in live environment.
My question is: How the code compiles at point 1 though the return type is different and also at point 2 we extract `String[]`.

P.S.: My eclipse snapshot [image]

Comment: Your `request.getParameterMap()` is raw so it does not complain.

Comment: If it's true that it's running since ages, then it's probably not Java EE 6 API and in the [Java EE 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()) it's just a raw map.

Comment: It is running in java-6. But today I am porting this application to java-7 and java-7 started to complain about it.

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but i think older compiler changes this:

```
Map<String, String> vars = request.getParameterMap();
```

into this (raw map):

```
Map vars = request.getParameterMap();
```

So it should run fine.
But it seems it has been changed in Java7. I can't find the exact link, but these may help:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html

Comment: Neither of your links supports your claim. The second one appears to be completely irrelevant.

Comment: Have a look to RFE: 7062745 and RFE: 7057297. Not the exact same cases than here, but some changes have been done on generic types management in Java7 (2nd link removed).

Comment: Another track: if you decompile servlet-api.jar from Tomcat7 for instance (containing HttpServletRequest implementations), the output of getParameterMap() is a raw map.

Comment: Neither of those RFEs appears in your link. Decompilation has nothing to with it. Nobody is disputing that types are erased. The more interesting question is what does javap print as the method signature.

Comment: ... Yes they appear. Just scroll down to "Important RFEs Addressed in Java SE 7" section.